# Access comment nodes outside <html> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm developing a chrome extension that reads html comments from a page and render them in an action popup.

However, I don't know how to (and if it's possible) to fetch some comments that are before and after the `<html>` tag. For example:

```
<!-- test test test -->
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

In jQuery, `$("html").before()` and `$("html").after()` both returns the same as `$("html")`.

Is it possible do fetch those types of comments using either jQuery or pure Javascript?

Edit: the page with the comments looks like this:

```
<!-- Comment I'd like to fetch -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" >
<head>
<title>Featured Designers for WOMEN</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
```

Comment: I think that HTML comments don't are appended to DOM tree.

Comment: `jQuery.before()` and `jQuery.after()` *inserts* content :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this document:

```
<!-- comment 1 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- comment 2 -->
<html>
<body>
hello world
</body>
</html>
```

You get the first comment like this:

```
document.firstChild.nodeValue
```

The second comment is found like this:

```
document.childNodes[2].nodeValue
```

To get all comments underneath `document`:

```
var nodes = document.childNodes;
for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i !== len; ++i) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeType === 8) {
        console.log('Found comment' + nodes[i].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jack, to get the second comment, it probably works. But document.firstChild.nodeValue returns null (at least on chrome).

Comment: @fegemo I've tested it on Chrome actually; but the last part of my answer should work though.

Comment: @fegemo It doesn't work in fiddle, because fiddle strips comments.

Comment: @fegemo I've tested your exact HTML on a blank page and running that JavaScript will output the single comment to console.

Comment: You are right, @Jack. I don't know what's happening, but it's working now. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the response!

Comment: The same idea works to get comments nested within an element (let's call that element the "parent" element), BUT the first child element of that parent will not be the comment element if the parent's opening tag and comment child opening tag are not textually touching. In other words, if there is a line return (eg, done for formatting purposes) or any space/text at all after the parent tag, the first child will be a text node while the second child will then be the comment node.

Answer (score 0):

`document.firstChild` should do it.

Comment: `document.firstChild` is returning the DOCTYPE tag

Answer (score 0):

`$("html").siblings();` This will return all the dom object elements at the same level as the html tag I believe. I wanted to confirm by using JSfiddle but I'm receviing Javascript errors on their website using IE8 right now. I can confirm later when I get home if it doesn't work for you in your testing.

Comment: `$("html").siblings()` returned an empty array

Comment: What does the html look like?